# Wallpaper with a calendar

Tags: linux, wallpaper, calendar

I was thinking about how they do a wallpaper that displays a calendar and highlight today's day, like when you just install an OS and has the deafult wallpaper that also shows the machine system information, but without beeing an app because that could make the the calendar app stop working all day and save a bit of the machine resources, anyone know how they do it?
And if it's not much work explain it to me?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/77065/use-a-calendar-as-desktop-wallpaper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a program called ***Conky*** on your PC which will display selected information on your desktop with transparency.

Comment: Thanks i'll do that

Comment: If this answers your question, then please mark the question as answered.